# How to update C# version without using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, updates, atom-editor

I don't use Visual Studio and I want to update my C# version to 8.0.
I tried to look up how to do it, but everything I found was for Visual Studio.
How can I update C# without using Visual Studio?

Comment: Since VS does not actually compile C# code... please clarify how you do compile your code so it is clear what picks compiler's version.

Comment: You can specify language version in project file, but you need to compile it with compiler which supports 8 version

Comment: @Fabio Indeed it is trivial if they use .csproj files...

Comment: I would assume you're using C# with dotnet. If yes, please add which version you're using. They're not all compatible with C# 8

Comment: i compile it in cmd, im using an older version right now since my windows isnt updated but i wanted to find out how to get the .csproj file before updating windows and installing .NET 4.8

Comment: Typically the language server used by an editor (VSCode or Atom) from OmniSharp assumes you have at least a valid project file (.csproj), so you have to get used to that. Otherwise, you have to hack your own language server/editor extension out.

Comment: Yes i realized i jeed the csproj file but how do i get it?

Answer (score 2):

In `.csproj` file under root `Project` element find or add [`LangVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) tag like this:

```
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: It is indeed the answer *if* they use .csproj files.

Comment: Where do i find .csproj?

Comment: Assuming that you are using omni-sharp in atom - open folder containing your project and browse it. If you have standard set up in the root you will have `.sln` file and bunch of folders, check that folders.

Comment: I dont have anything in my project folder, and how do i check if i use omnisharp?

Comment: @Octavylon How do you program in C#?

Comment: with atom editor

Comment: @Guru Stron Oh by the way i dont actually have nothing in my project folder, i meant i dont have any of the things u stated in it

Comment: @Octavylon what do you have in your project folder(on disk I mean)

Comment: i have my .cs and .exe files ( i solved the problem btw)

Comment: @Octavylon how did you solve it?

Comment: i found out how to create .csproj files to choose my c# version